# Error setting up python protobuf

Tags: python-2.7, protocol-buffers

Steps I'm following for installation:

```
`git clone https://github.com/google/protobuf
 cd python/
 sudo python setup.py install`
```

But I get the following error:

```
`running install
 running bdist_egg
 running egg_info
 creating protobuf.egg-info
 writing requirements to protobuf.egg-info/requires.txt
 writing protobuf.egg-info/PKG-INFO
 writing namespace_packages to protobuf.egg-info/namespace_packages.txt
 writing top-level names to protobuf.egg-info/top_level.txt
 writing dependency_links to protobuf.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
 writing manifest file 'protobuf.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
 reading manifest file 'protobuf.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
 reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
 warning: no previously-included files found matching 'google/protobuf/internal/*_pb2.py'
 warning: no previously-included files found matching 'google/protobuf/internal/*.proto'
 warning: no previously-included files matching '*_test.py' found under directory 'google'
 warning: no previously-included files matching '*_test.proto' found under directory 'google'
 warning: no previously-included files matching 'unittest*_pb2.py' found under directory 'google'
 warning: no previously-included files matching '*.dll' found anywhere in distribution
 warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
 warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyo' found anywhere in distribution
 warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
 writing manifest file 'protobuf.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
 installing library code to build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg
 running install_lib
 running build_py
 Generating google/protobuf/descriptor_pb2.py...
 protoc is not installed nor found in ../src.  Please compile it or install  the binary package.`
```

Not sure what needs to be done. Please help! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to build the protocol buffer compiler (`protoc`) first. At the top of the Git repo just run `./autogen.sh && ./configure && make`.